# Why does my scanf while loop not exit when consuming newline characters?

Tags: c, while-loop, newline, scanf

```
// Some initialization code

dup2(fd[0], fileno(stdin));

// This process is receiving the output of "ls -1"

while (scanf("%[^\n]s", someCharArray) > 0) {
    scanf("%*c");
    printf("%s\n", someCharArray);
}
```

This successfully prints all the files. However, the loop never exits. If I take away `scanf("%*c")`, it does exit, but only the first filename is printed.

I would expect the consuming of the newline character will prepare the outer `scanf` to scan the next filename, which is what it seems to be doing. But after the final filename is scanned, I expect the nested `scanf` to not scan anything. Then the outer `scanf` to not scan anything either. And the while loop exits.

> Why is this happening?

Comment: The `s` at the end of your conversion-specifer does no do what you think it does.

Comment: You might want to checl e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: I would have thought just using `fgets` and trimming off the newline would be easier.

Comment: The strange thing is, this code works for me. I opened `popen("ls -l", "r");` , and the loop does finish after printing all the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop does not exit as it is waiting for more input.

You can

1. send a pair of `\n\n` so `scanf("%[^\n]...` returns 0 as it fails to scan the 2nd `\n`, or
2. close `stdin` (in an implementation specific way) so `scanf()` return `EOF`, a negative number.

Better to use `fgets()`. [@WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105160/why-does-my-scanf-while-loop-not-exit-when-consuming-newline-characters/36105332#comment59852528_36105160)  Although it is still unclear under what condition you want the loop to end (other than `stdin` closure).

```
while (fgets(someCharArray, sizeof someCharArray, stdin)) {
  // Lop off potential trailing \n if desired
  someCharArray[strcspn(someCharArray, "\n")] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", someCharArray);
}
```

Note: the `"s"` in `scanf("%[^\n]s", someCharArray)` serves no purpose - drop it.  Also this format, without a width, does not limit the maximum number of character scanned in to `someCharArray` and should not be used in quality code.

---

> I would expect the consuming of the newline character will prepare the outer scanf to scan the next filename, which is what it seems to be doing.

Yes - that right.  The earlier `scanf("%[^\n]...` has no limit on the number of characters scanned which could lead to undefined behavior (UB), so why expect the rest of code to behave?

> But after the final filename is scanned, I expect the nested scanf to not scan anything.

If the final final filename has a `'\n'` after it, `scanf("%*c");` will consume it.  If the final filename lacks any following character, `scanf("%*c");` will patiently wait for a character.  If the input stream has been close, it will return `EOF` instead of waiting.  Code does not report/test the result of `scanf("%*c");` so we are left to guess.

> Then the outer scanf to not scan anything either. And the while loop exits.

True, if the first character to scan is a `'\n'`, it will remain in `stdin` and `scanf()` will return 0. if `stdin` is closed, `scanf()` will return the negative number `EOF`.